# Is positive Borel measure (which is mutually singular to Lebesgue measure), inner regular?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am studying Real and Complex Analysis, Rudin. [image]

According to my understanding, this theorem is proved by the claim that $$ \mu (W_{j, N}) \lt 3^{k} N/j $$.
The book proves this claim by using smaller compact set $K$ contained in $W_{j, N}$. And this logic holds with assumption that $\mu$ is inner regular. However, I have trouble to prove it. Though it is positive Borel measure on Euclidean space, there is no guarantee about finiteness of $\mu$. Could anybody please explain inner regularity?

Comment: This question has been asked before. Rudin assumes that $\mu$ is finite on compact sets but I don't think he stated it explicitly. Regularity is true for any measure which is finite on compact sets.